# What is the right approach for automated command unregistring in quake-like console?

Tags: c++

I want to implement a simple Quake-like console. This implementation is roughly based on the implementation in Doom 3:

```
class Console
{
public:
    ...

    typedef boost::function<void(const Arguments&)> Callback;

    void register_command(const std::string& name, const Callback& callback);
    void unregister_command(const std::string& name);
};
```

However, I plan to support loadable modules that can also be unloaded. When the module is unloaded, it needs to unregister its commands. Unregistring them one by one is tedious and error-prone. How to automate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your `Console::register_command` function return an object. This object (or a copy thereof) has one member function: `unregister`. Calling it will unregister the particular registration it was given.

Therefore, each module can have a `std::vector<>` of these objects. It can unregister all of them as part of its destructor.

You don't want the object's destructor to do it, unless you make the object like a `shared_ptr` with reference counting. Or if you're using C++11 and can make the object move-only.

Note that the object will need to reference the `Console` object it was created from. So you can have lifetime issues, where the `Console` has been destroyed yet not all of these objects it created are gone. Dealing with this could involve use of `shared_from_this`, where `Console` is always stored in a `shared_ptr` (whether `boost::shared_ptr` or C++11 `std::shared_ptr`). The registration objects would have a `weak_ptr` to the `Console`, so they can test to see if it is still alive.